# Mysql Dump directly into SFTP or into another server

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I just have a quick question : I have a MariaDb Database ( with 1Tb of data) running on a dedicated server, I only have 2gb left on my storage and I would like to backup a few databases on my SFTP server or on another dedicated server directly since I don't have any storage left to store them temporary.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the ability to connect to your MariaDB as a SQL connection from another server? Pulling the dump from another server is probably going to be easier than running it and dumping it elsewhere if this is happening over the internet. If you have another server on the same network doing this to an NFS mount would probably work. 1 TB is a lot.

Comment: See if [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/400203/how-to-pipe-data-to-sftp-connection) helps.

Comment: Windows?  Or Linux?

Answer (score 0):

On a separate machine with perhaps 2TB of disk space free:

```
 mysqldump -u ... -p... -h mysql_server ... > dumpfile.sql
```

It will take time.  Be sure to get the correct parameters -- routines, etc may not be dumped by default.

I suggest 2TB on the target machine because *sometimes* the dump is bigger than the database.  (Sometimes it is smaller.)  A "0" in a `BIGINT` takes 8 bytes in the database, but only 2 bytes in the dump.  Some other things are 3x bigger in the dump.

In the future, be sure to keep more free disk space than the largest table.  This is to allow for `ALTER`, which can *sometimes* help keep away from "out of disk space".

If the "S" part of SFTP is what you are after, check on "SSL" settings in MySQL.

(I don't know if SFTP can be used to "pipe" data; I suspect it can only handle "files", which you don't have.)